# Scheduling a function in google cloud sql - Postgresql DB

Tags: scheduler, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to schedule a function to periodically run and delete records from my google cloudsql (Postgresql) database. I want this to run a couple of times a day and will run under 10 minutes. What options do I have to schedule this function?

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 2):

Your best option will be to use [Cloud Scheluder](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart) to schedule a job that publishes to a Pub/Sub topic. Then, have a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-console) subscribed to this topic so it get's triggered by the message sent.

You can configure this job to run as a [Daily routine](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules?hl=en_US&_ga=2.15040560.-762591278.1543924925#defining_the_job_schedule) x times a day.

Answer (score 1):

Try pgAgent 
pgAgent is a job scheduling agent for Postgres databases, capable of running multi-step batch or shell scripts and SQL tasks on complex schedules.

pgAgent is distributed independently of pgAdmin. You can download [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/pgagent.html) from the download area of the pgAdmin website.

Comment: pgAgent is not supported in google cloud nor Amazon. They want you to use their own cloud function for security and also for money reasons.